# Consultas sobre JSON Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Obtuve datos de una consulta SQL con AJAX, y en JQuery obtengo los resultados de la siguiente manera:

```
 var Data = $.parseJSON(result.d);

 var datos = Data.Resultados; // .Resultados es el nombre de mi tabla con los resultados de SQL
```

Es posible con JQuery realizar consultas sobre ese JSON??

NOTA: He probado .filter pero nada funciona =(

```
var aux = Data.filter(function (i,n){
        return n.Id== "0001";
    });
```

Comment: ¿Quieres aplicar filtros sobre tu JSON recibido?

Comment: Siii! Es posible??? Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Se puede en el sentido de usar ciclos y tu propia lógica de programación para simular algo como una consulta SQL para filtrar datos. Pero consultas tipo SQL sobre un JSON no existe tal implementación, hasta donde yo conozco.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que realizaré varios cambios sobre ese JSON, para una función necesito quitar ciertos campos, para otra necesito mostrar los que en un campo cumplan con una condición, es decir, necesito eliminar campos (nombres de JSON) y obtener solo los que en cierto campo tengan cierto valor, no sé si me dí a entender

Comment: Con Jquery no de manera directa o facil, pero existen otras librerías que pueden ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres realizar consultas contra tu JSON puedes utilizar [json-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-query).

#### Ejemplo

```
jsonQuery('people[country=ES].name', { data: Data })
```

Pero creo que sería mejor que realizases tu mismo el filtrado y mapeado de tus datos, por ejemplo:

```
const data = [{ age: 10 }, { age: 5 }, { age: 20 }, { age: 15 }, { age: 30 }];

const filtrados = data.filter(v => v.age > 17); // [{age:20}, {age:30}]
const mapeados = data.map(v => { age: v.age + 1 });
```

Comment: Me parece muy interesante! Lo intentaré y te informaré mi resultado. Y si quisiera borrar un age??

Comment: Entonces utiliza mejor el map, puedes unir los metodos, primero filtrar, luego mapear, luego etc.

Comment: Mmmmm supongamos que tengo algo así: 

{ "Id": 2, "Nombre": "X", "Apellido": "A"}, Cómo podría borrar el elemento "Apellido" por ejemplo?

Comment: array.map(object => {
  delete object['Apellido'];
  return object;
})

Comment: Hola! Intenté tu solución pero me dice que .filter no está definido =/ hay algún otro método para poder filtrar? algo similar al LIKE de SQL??

Comment: Si no está definido es porque filter es un método de los arrays y lo estás aplicando sobre un objeto.